# Removing ? from document.location.search

Tags: javascript, replace

How can I place document.location.search into a variable w/o the '?' Is there a simple regex, or can I just ignore the first character?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No problem

```
window.location.search.substr(1);
```

### Edit

I didn't even think about it the first time, but you should refer to window.location, not document.location.  It has the broadest browser support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.location#Notes

Comment: Indeed the best solution. Mine was unnecessarily complicated, so I have deleted my answer.

Comment: String.substr is deprecated, instead use String.substring or String.slice

Comment: It is? Don't see a mention here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr or here http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2000/javascript/1.5/guide/obj.html#1008731

Where can I find this info?

Comment: Is it a given (and compatible amongst all modern browsers) that location.search will begin with a question mark?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace the "?" character with an empty string:

```
var searchWithoutQuestionMark = document.location.search.replace('?', '');
```

Steve